# Yet Another Simple Chess Rebus

Tags: rebus, chess, movies

*This is an entry to the [19th Fortnightly Topic Challenge](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5614/fortnightly-topic-challenge-19-unconventional-tag-fusion?cb=1)*

Here is a relatively simple **chess rebus**:

[image]

Hope it will be answered soon. If not, will add hints. :)

To Make it not too broad and take you closer to the intended answer

[image]

**Hint** Added. Check the **tag**.

Comment: Aah, [this escalated quickly](http://imgur.com/E21g2uu)!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

How about:

> Batman Begins

Because

> The Knight is on B4, and Batman Begins is the prequel to The Dark Knight (Before The Dark Knight and The Dark Knight Rises)?

Comment: Perfect. Correct answer.

Answer (score 7):

> The Dark Knight

and

> The Dark Knight Rises

Comment: Almost there. Will add a hint.

Comment: This has to be the correct answer if you've added that hint, and yeah also Batman!!

Answer (score 4):

The answer is

> before night

or

> the night before

because

> The knight is on b4.

Comment: Good. But not perfect. +1  :)

Answer (score 4):

Is the answer :

> "**The darkest hour of the night came just before the dawn**" - The Alchemist by Paulo Coelho.

As we can see that :

> **Dark knight**, no Batman pun intended, **is on b4** and facing west direction. There is white curve (maybe because of early morning sunlight) on his back. (although there should have been a shadow also)

Answer (score 4):

Is it

> Before the night is dark

As Silenus pointed out,

> the knight is on b4.

Answer (score 2):

With the hint we have

> on the night before the night in question

because

> the knight is on b4 and is in a question mark